# Capturar evento de manipulação do mês do componente Schedule

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-5.2

Ao utilizar o componente [Schedule](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml) do Primefaces é possível manipular os eventos dos botões que alteram o mês atual do calendário, os botões marcados com o círculo na imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero capturar a partir do evento associado aos "botões de navegação" o mês selecionado e realizar a partir deste evento uma consulta por demanda, ou seja, uma consulta que leva em consideração o mês selecionado pelo botão de navegação.

**Esta implementação é possível? Se sim, como devo proceder?**

Comment: Você quer pegar o mês que está exibindo depois de clicar no botão?

Comment: @Rafael, a captura do mês é algo secundário. Quero agir na "change" do componente de navegação do mês, para dessa forma carregar os eventos por demanda, conforme o mês selecionado. Ajustei a pergunta para ficar mais clara a necessidade.

Comment: Você já viu o evento `viewChange` ? Ele é disparado quando a view é mudada.

Comment: @Rafael, fiz um teste rápido e o evento não foi chamado ao clicar no botões de navegação.

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa capturar os eventos dos botões, siga o 3o exemplo do [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml) do primefaces(Lazy Schedule), você deve carregar os eventos no método `loadEvents(Date start, Date end)` (linha 38)